# Ansible: How to joint string and integer to become new string

Tags: linux, ansible

I need assistance for ansible playbok on how to joint/combine string (linux) and number (0002) to be linux0002. Also how I can use %04d to format the integer 2 after arithmetic operation.

Comment: If  '0002' is a number it's the number 2. Right? I read the question: " Combine string 'linux' and number 2 to be string 'linux0002'.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: *"**How to joint/combine string (linux) and number (0002) to be linux0002?**"*

A: Use [format](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-filters.format), e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ _string ~ '%04d'|format(_number) }}"
      vars:
        _string: linux
        _number: 2
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: linux0002
```

---

Q: *"**How I can use %04d to format the integer 2 after an arithmetic operation?**|*

A: The same code works after an arithmetic operation, e.g.

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ _string ~ '%04d'|format(_number + 1) }}"
      vars:
        _string: linux
        _number: 2
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: linux0003
```

---

**Notes**

- The variable '_number: 0002' is equivalent to '_number: 2'

Comment: It is working. Thanks Vladimir Botka